# Why is the search box not working by default in Jquery Datatables?

Tags: datatables

I am typing in the search box in an attempt to narrow my results. When I am typing the screen flashes like it is trying to narrow the results but the results do not change.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

       var table =  $('#activeProjects').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "../api/Project/GetAll/",
                "dataSrc": ""
            },

            "columns": [
            { "data": "ProjectName" },
            { "data": "ProjectNumber" },
            { "data": "ProjectManager" },
            { "data": "ProjectArchitect" }
            ]
       });
    });
</script>
```

I get back a List of data from the server but I an unable to search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using server side data, DataTables won't grab all data and filter it on the client, instead it will rely on the server to do all the processing and send only the parts that will be displayed to the user.

You have to implement the search in your server side script, in this case `../api/Project/GetAll/`.

[DataTables sends a few parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) back to the server. Look for the parameters `search[value]` and `columns[i][searchable]` and filter your data accordingly.

Comment: Could you show an example of what the api Action should look like?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "api Action". If you want to see an implementation of the server side processing for DataTables, check out [DataTables's Server-side processing](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) example page, below the data table there is a box, click "Server-side script" and check that out. Actually, that file and the `ssp.class.php` file are included in the distribution of the plugin under `\examples\server_side\scripts`.

Comment: That is my problem then, I am running the server-side in ASP.NET WEB API 2. I will try and find examples of it in that. Thanks

Comment: The arguments sent back to your Web API will be exactly the same as the php examples. DataTables is server-agnostic. Just read parameters from `HttpContext.Request` and filter your data server-side accordingly (e.g. LINQ, dynamic SQL, etc)